# Missing xmlns:loc from C# generated XML from XSD.exe

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XSD from which i generated class using xsd.exe using this command   line arguments:

`xsd /c /eld /order /namespace:GUI fornituraRLI12_v1.xsd`

everything works like a charm but the xml generated using my application
look like this:
(only few raws...)

instead of the original that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<loc:Fornitura xmlns:loc="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1" xmlns:cm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common:v2" xmlns:reg="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:reg:v1" xmlns:sc="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:common:v2">
<loc:Intestazione>
<loc:CodiceFornitura>RLI12</loc:CodiceFornitura>
<loc:TipoFornitore>1</loc:TipoFornitore><loc:CodiceFiscaleFornitore>FRRGCR69R16D142W</loc:CodiceFiscaleFornitore>
<loc:SpazioServizioTelematico>`
```

I got this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Fornitura xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1">
 <Intestazione>
 <CodiceFornitura>RL12</CodiceFornitura>
 <TipoFornitore>10</TipoFornitore>
```

I don't know how insert

```
 <loc:Fornitura xmlns:loc="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1" xmlns:cm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common:v2" xmlns:reg="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:reg:v1" xmlns:sc="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:common:v2">`
```

instead of

```
<Fornitura xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1">
```

2)insert `<loc:` before every tag and insert all namespace (loc: cm: reg: etc).
I've tried using xsd2code playing with some parameters but the result was the same. I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The two XML examples are the same.

The first example uses a specific namespace prefix `xmlns:loc='urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1'`.

The second example uses a default namespace `xmlns='urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1'`

Comment: Thanks Richard, but how I can change the default namespace and insert <loc: <reg: in every tag?

Comment: You do not have to insert a specific namespace prefix.  XML does not require this.  As long as the namespace is the same the document is valid.

Comment: Probably you are right but when i generate the xml it look different in namespace and in tags, so the xml is rejected from a italian government utility that check correct syntax of the xml submitted. If you desire i can't send the xsd of the class.... and an example of the government xml generated to see differences...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Was sufficient add this piece of code:

`XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    ns.Add("loc", "urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:loc:v1");
                    ns.Add("cm", "urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common:v2");
                    ns.Add("reg", "urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:reg:v1");
                    ns.Add("sc", "urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:common:v2");
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, fornitura,ns);`